# External Microphone not does not work on Linux Mint 20 Ulyana

Tags: linux-mint, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

**Issue**

I cannot capture audio using an external microphone on my Linux Mint 20 Ulyana system. In `Sound Settings` under the `Input` tab, when I select the external microphone from the `Device` list, the `Input level` shows zero/nil, irrespective of the `Volume` slider position.

[image: Screenshot of Sound Settings detailing the above issue.]

However, I can still use the internal microphone without any issue.

**Things I have tried so far**

1. I have tried three different external microphones, including a bluetooth device. I have eliminated the possibility of an issue with Microphone jack and the microphone pin(s).
2. Checked whether the device is muted in `alsamixer`. It looks like the device is unmuted, as I did not see an `MM` under the device.

Here's my system information: https://termbin.com/31ml

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, also Mint 20. I tried to upgrade to kernel 5.8.0-25, but it did not help.

```
System:    Kernel: 5.8.0-25-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Cinnamon 4.6.7 
           wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 20 Ulyana base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
........
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio vendor: Lenovo 
           driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 chip ID: 8086:0c0c 
           Device-2: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio vendor: Lenovo 
           driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 chip ID: 8086:8c20 
           Device-3: Logitech [G533 Wireless Headset Dongle] type: USB 
           driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus ID: 3-1:10 chip ID: 046d:0a66 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-25-generic
```

The internal microphone is working fine.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hi People,
I've been through this for days too and finally I've solved it.

1. Open your terminal
2. type [alsamixer]
3. Validate by hiting [Enter]
4. Get all the Headphones values from -65,25 <>-62,25 up to 100<>100
5. Go to the Auto-Mute Mode
6. Set its value to [Disabled]
7. Close the settings with [Esc] button